# ADF Pipeline not getting triggered after trying to execute in Debug mode

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I was trying to execute a pipeline in Debug mode. After clicking on Debug, notification says the pipeline started running but there is no response there after and the output screen also shows no entry of the pipeline being executed. Anyone have faced this issue before ?

Comment: Did you validate the pipeline?

Comment: yes Joseph. Validation successful with no errors.

Comment: Can you add some more detail? What activity types are you running? FYI - the default timeout for every activity is 7 days.

Comment: The pipeline usually truncate and load some tables and the final activity will do join of all the tables refreshed and load it into another table. BTW i created a new branch and executed the pipeline over there and it was successful. Still, i didn't get to know why the pipeline failed to kick off in the specific branch.